# @media (max-width: 780px) {.video-grid: { grid-template-column: 1fr 1fr }} not taking changes when browser reaches the size

Tags: html, css, grid, media-queries

I'm recreating the Youtube homepage from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G3e-cpL7ofc&pp=ygUIaHRtbCBjc3M%3D
and almost finishing up the project. I'm trying to make the videos placed in two instead of three videos in a row when the browser width reaches 780px and under.
I can make the videos placed in 4 when the browser is 781px and over just fine. Here is my code:

```
@media (min-width: 781px), (max-width: 999px) {
  .video-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .video-grid {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  }`
}
`
```

It works just fine but somehow my code below doesn't work:
``

@media (max-width: 780px) {
.video-grid {

```
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
```

}`
}

I looked it up and just added the viewport meta in the head element but it didn't seem to solve the problem also its not responsive on mobile view[The user-picture is cut in half as shown below.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6a8WH.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In a media quarry, it's necessary to add min-width and max-width. Just add min-width or max-width.

check this code it's work:

```
@media (min-width: 781px) {
    .video-grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
    .video-grid {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

}

@media (max-width: 780px) {
    .video-grid {

        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;

    }
}
```

Comment: Tysm! it  works. Idk why I was having a problem adding min-width and max-width for the 1fr 1fr 1fr query when the original creator wasn't having any issues.